# puzzling php parser error

Tags: php, parsing, php-internals

Ok maybe not so puzzling, but here it is.

I was messing around and noticed this, typing just `<?php` in a file, just that, no space after that, nothing else just the tag, throws a parse error.

With a single space it works fine. I was wondering if anyone knows why the parser chokes, since it is perfectly okay otherwise to omit the closing tag.
Thanks.

Comment: My php interpreter doesn't throw a parse error in that situation.

Comment: Mine does (`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/chris/test.php on line 1`) PHP version is `5.3.3-7+squeeze3`.

Comment: No idea why, but I can confirm it with PHP5.3.6+Suhosin, 2.6.32-3-amd64 linux kernel.

Comment: Definitely puzzling. I wonder why I can't duplicate it. PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2

Comment: Hm, seems they _just_ added support for it, might still be broken: [_'In PHP 5.2 and earlier, the parser does not allow the <?php opening tag to be the only thing in a file. This is allowed as of PHP 5.3.'_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

Comment: @PaulPRO: most common editors add a sneaky newline in there. How does `echo -n '<?php' > /tmp/test.php; php /tmp/test.php;` work out? Still no error?

Comment: Ah, Good point. Thanks Wrikken, I managed to replicate it now. Didn't realize my editor was doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) says:

> In PHP 5.2 and earlier, the parser does not allow the `<?php` opening
>   tag to be the only thing in a file. This is allowed as of PHP 5.3.

With that said, in PHP 5.3, if you have `short_open_tags` set to `On` in your `php.ini` file, the error still shows up.

Comment: Ack, short_open_tags is indeed the difference between parse error or not in my php version (5.3.6)

Comment: Ah. That explains why I have it though I'm on php 5.3.5 I guess it thinks I'm trying to use shorttags'. And the 'p' after isn't valid php. :)

Answer (score 2):

This answered in the [PHP Documentation for Basic Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php):

> In PHP 5.2 and earlier, the parser does not allow the `<?php` opening
>   tag to be the only thing in a file. This is allowed as of PHP 5.3.

However, by the OP it seems that the opening tag + space is allowed (i.e. *not the only thing in a file*). In addition, from the comments, it would seem that this is not the case for distro versions or otherwised *patched*.

Answer (score 1):

My PHP version:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: Mar 17 2011 20:56:13) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
```

The code in question:

```
$ echo -n "<?php" | php
<?php
```

Adding some more next to `<?php`:

```
$ echo -n "<?php/**/" | php
<?php/**/
```

or

```
$ echo -n "<?php;" | php
<?php;
```

and then a space:

```
$ echo -n "<?php " | php
```

(finally empty output).

That PHP version is not giving me a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end` type of message for the examples above, but it does with this:

```
$ echo -n "<?php x" | php -d display_errors=1

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in - on line 1
```

Hope it helps. In my eyes this looks like that the input is treated just as text until a whitespace follows up the `<?php` opening sequence.